# How to continue monitoring iBeacon when screen is off in iOS?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ibeacon, locationmanager, screen-off

I am developing an iOS app to monitor iBeacons. It works well in both foreground and background. I also need it to keep monitoring even when the screen is off. Now my problem is, when I turn off the screen with the shoulder button, NSLog shows that the iBeacon signal goes off (RSSI=0, beacon.accuracy=-1.0) accordingly, and 10 seconds later, there is no beacon found at all, while the delegate method locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion: is called continuously. It seems that the app is running when the screen is off but iOS turns off the location service for iBeacon ranging. I tried to set "locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;" but still doesn't work. Is there any advice on this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try setting this locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES; This is necessary for iOS 9

Comment: This does not sound normal.  Can you reproduce this behavior on a second iOS device?

Comment: I tried "locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;" just now, still doesn't work. The iOS version on my device is 9.2.

Comment: Yes, the behaviour is all the same for iPhone 5s, 6, 6plus. So I guess there should be some easter egg I missed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're doing **ranging** instead of monitoring. Ranging only works when the app is active—either in the foreground or in the background. The catch is, iOS will automatically put an app to sleep a few seconds after you navigate away from it, or lock the screen.

What you have to keep in mind is, there's really no such thing as "permanent background state" on iOS. Apps run in the background for some limited time while transitioning to the suspended state (to let them, e.g., finish uploads/downloads), and there are also Background Modes that sometimes enable an app to run in the background, but these are usually reserved for very specific apps—e.g., the "audio" Background Mode means an app can be running in the background as long as it plays music, etc. There is a Background Mode for "location" services, but it's reserved for turn-by-turn navigation apps.

Beacon **monitoring** however continues running even if your app goes to sleep, or gets terminated by the iOS due to memory pressure. When you go in or out of range of a beacon, iOS will launch your app into the background to handle the event, giving it a few seconds (which you can extend up to a few minutes with a [Background Execution Task](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)) to do so (you can range during that time), but then it's back to sleep.

You might also want to take a look at this question:
[Receive signal from beacon while app is in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984778/receive-signal-from-beacon-while-app-is-in-the-background)